# Installing Gnome on a Raspberry Pi 400

Tags: software-installation, debian

I have a Raspberry Pi 400 with Debian Bookworm and LXDE as graphical user interface. After installing Gnome and rebooting, LXDE appears again.

I tried both "sudo apt install gnome/stable" and "sudo tasksel" and there were no error messages or warnings during the installation process. The only problem is that LXDE instead of Gnome starts. On the LXDE login screen I have not seen a button to switch between different installed desktop environments.

Moreover, I tried to allocate more RAM to the GPU, but I have found neither in raspi-config nor in config.txt an appropiate option.

Comment: Conventionally under X, if you install multiple DE's, you'd have to configure the [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager) as to which one to use; often this option will be present on the login screen if you look around (presuming you aren't using autologin).  I haven't used the default one on RpiOS (`lightdm` I think) enough to say for sure. Bookworm by default **uses Wayland, not X11/Xorg**, but as far as I've noticed DM's take that into account (eg., on my Fedora desktop  `sddm` gives me a choice of DE's *and* Wayland or X).